# how to format a cell color to match another cell color that changes with conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I cant seem to adapt this script I found here or figure out how to ask a question on the thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403434/9676680

is the script.  I tried to adapt it to the cell and range I need colored but the script comes back with an error in line 4.  I dont write code so seeing if the original programmer or someone can help me?

I have a cell to turn a color based on text.  But then I want a range of cells to change based on that cells color.

Comment: it sounds as if you _want a range of cells to change based on_ **text**. Why not change all of them at one time rather than just the one?

Comment: i dont want it based on text.  I want the range to change based on the color of the one cell.

Comment: because that one cell had certain text. So the impetus for change is the text. But hey, your ball game.

Comment: What's wrong with conditional formatting? I'd offer a solution but your question is too vague for anything but generalities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41387051/9676680  this is the link to the orginal question I linked before.  I want to change the color of one cell then another range of cells get the same color.  The original question is quite specific which is why I linked it.